# TabBar's index changes when it hides

Tags: flutter, view, tabbar

I'm building a scaffold with a TabBar as BottomNavigationBar and a TabView as body. The problem is that when I open the keyboard to input data in a form for some reason TabBar changes index (Even if inside TabView doesn't). Why does this happen? How can i provent it?

```
    class _SignState extends State<Sign> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  static Container navBar;
  static TabBarView pages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

    print(tabController.index);
    void _goLogin() {
      //  tabController.animateTo(tabController.previousIndex);
    }

    pages = TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: [
      LoginPage(
        keyRoot: widget.keyRoot,
      ),
      RegisterPage(
        onRegistered: _goLogin,
      ),
    ]);

    navBar = Container(
      height: 50,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 0.3,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        style: BorderStyle.solid))),
          ),
          TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    blurRadius: 1,
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              tabs: [Text('Accedi'), Text('Registrati')]),
        ],
      ),
    );

    // Main page

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _returnTop(),
          Expanded(
            child: pages,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      persistentFooterButtons: _returnButtons(),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        child: navBar,
      ),
    );
  }

      Widget _returnTop() {
        return Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Image.asset('assets/logo_sign.png')),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 20,
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              child: Text('salta >'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home", arguments: widget.keyRoot);
              },
            ),
          )
        ]);
      }

      List<Widget> _returnButtons() {
        return [
          Text('oppure con'),
          IconButton(
              //TODO: Aggiungere funzioni
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.googlePlusG),
              tooltip: 'Login con Google',
              onPressed: () {}),
          IconButton(
              //TODO: Aggiungere funzioni
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebook),
              tooltip: 'Login con Facebook',
              onPressed: () {}),
          IconButton(
              //TODO: Aggiungere funzioni
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitter),
              tooltip: 'Login con Twitter',
              onPressed: () {}),
        ];
      }
    }
```

Modified: Thereit is my entire code :)

Comment: please put the code of your implementation

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have added the TabController initializer inside build method. Then what happens is when the keyboard appears, the build method is run and the tab controller is initialized again. The correct way is to initialize the TabController in initState method.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense, I'll try it as soon as possible, but it seems right and consistent. I should have imagined it, everytime there was a rebuild it printed the index. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome mate.. Mark as correct and vote if it works